# select count distinct over another value doesn't work

Tags: count, distinct, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I don't know why Snowflake can't calculate my value.
This table contains multiple periods for multiple Users, and a user can have X times the same period.

```
SELECT DISTINCT("Period"),COUNT(DISTINCT"Users")
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
```

I get the following result:

> SQL compilation error: ["TABLE"."Period"] is not a valid group by expression

What's wrong with my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:

```sql
SELECT "Period", COUNT(DISTINCT"Users")
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
GROUP BY "Period"
```

Once you want to get a `COUNT()`, `SELECT DISTINCT` won't work anymore - and instead you have to `GROUP BY`.